# ARM and x86, is necessary deal with Hardware Architecture compatibility in my situation?

Tags: node.js, x86, arm, endianness, coap

I have a coap server code running on my gateway which may have x86 or ARM architecture, which sends a Buffer to coap client in another hardware which may have x86 or ARM architecture, my question is, on a specific scenario where the client has x86 architecture and the server has ARM architecture, when the buffer is written by the server and the client parses the payload buffer will occur an uncompatibility, consequently an error?

obs: I ask this because x86 architecture is little-endian  and the ARM architecture is Big-endian.

Comment: arm is natively little endian.  you have to put extra work in to make it big

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To exchange raw binary data between systems of possibly different architectures, the data has to be put into a known canonical format.  The sender has to make sure it's in that known format and the recipient has to expect it in that known format.

For some things that's easy.  If it's merely an array of U8 values (unsigned 8-bit values), then that is already a known, canonical format.

But, if it's an array of U16, U32, U64, S16, S32, S64 values or any type of format containing those larger values, then you have to know if it's in big endian or little endian byte format.  You will need to decide what the interchange format is and make sure you put the data into that format before sending and the recipient needs to accept the data in that format, perhaps converting it into what it wants to use natively.

So, you can't just blindly send multi-byte data from a little endian architecture to a big endian architecture without converting it.  It is best to decide upon a specific interchange format, have the sender of the data make sure the data is converted to that interchange format and make sure the recipient is expecting the data in that interchange format.

FYI, for modest amounts of data, this is why non-binary formats like JSON exist and have become so popular because they are already a well-known standard that doesn't have endian ordering issues.

Answer (score -1):

The CoAP protocol works between machines of any endianness.

CoAP does not do any conversion on the data that is transported in the request/response payload, but the common formats there are well specified just as CoAP itself is.

Comment: Well, the CoAP protocol specifies that you send things in the protocol itself in network byte order.  It does not specify anything about the payload of data.  That is up to the sender which is what I think the OP is asking about in this question.

Comment: Good point -- can't downvote my own answer but boosted yours, I did miss the point about the payload buffer.

Comment: @jfriend00 is correctly about my problem, my only concern is how differente arquictetures will handle with the payload.

Answer (score -1):

**Most modern ARM CPUs are little-endian, same as x86.**  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).  Some ARM CPUs can run in either mode (bi-endian), but are normally run in little-endian mode.

This is opposite of "network byte order" that CoAP [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62599187/arm-and-x86-is-necessary-deal-with-hardware-arquicteture-compatibility-in-my-si#comment110703062_62599417) specifies for its protocol headers, but you can probably get away with sending your own raw payload data as little-endian if you want.